# execute patch file not work probably

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a **bat** file to execute several series command, for example I wrote this code:

```
c:
netsh
advance
```

but the problem that the first two lines execute, but the last one didn't so the result will be as shown below:

```
c:\>netsh
netsh>
```

but the result must be :

```
c:\>netsh
netsh>firewall
netsh firewall>
```

so the firewall is sub command of netsh family so how I can solve this problem ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `netsh -f script.txt` to feed a script to `netsh`.  Type `netsh /?` for details or online here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc778925(v=ws.10).aspx